# Development Pod Doesn't Have Class Prefix

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, cocoapods

I'm building a private pod and provided a class prefix when I ran `pod lib create MyPod`. It looks like the example app included in the workspace has the class prefix set, but the development pod doesn't. Because of that, I have to manually add my class prefix to each new file I create in my pod. (I realize that's not a lot of work.)

I currently have the field set on the Pods project but that is cleared during `pod install` or `pod update`. That's also not a good place to put it IMHO because that's technically for the entire Pods project, including any other pods that mine is dependent on.

You can add project settings to podspecs and podfiles, but I believe that adds it to the entire Pods project which I'm not convinced is the best solution.

**Is there a way to keep a class prefix for a development pod?**

I'm currently using Xcode 6.4 and cocoapods v0.37.2 on OSX 10.10.4